# Bootstrap navbar-toggle shows button but does nothing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, navbar

I'm not being able to toggle the navigation menus in my navbar. I've reproduced the problem in fiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/9bydt08L/3/ 
I've included necessary js and css also but don't know why its not working for me. Looked up every related questions in stackoverflow and tried everything possible but can't figure out where the error is. Can anyone point out where is the error please?

CSS and HTML:

```css
.navbar{
  background-color: #D9F7F6;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
body{
  background-color: #E6E7E7;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="main">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!--COLLAPSE BUTTON FOR NAVBAR MENU-->
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#menu-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">PRADIP KHADKA</a>
      </div><!--END NAVBAR HEADER-->
      <div class="nav-collapse navbar-collapse collapse" id="menu-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" id="navMenu">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SOCIAL MEDIA</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--END OF NAVBAR MENUS-->
    </div><!--END OF NAVBAR CONTAINER-->
  </div><!--END OF NAVBAR-->
</div><!--END OF MAIN CONTAINER-->
```

Comment: Looks like you have included jQuery.js after bootstrap JS file.
Put the jquery file above your bootstrap js .

TIP: Check your Browser console. It clearly shows error ("Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery" )

Comment: Thank you @sidzan for your tip and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the script matters. Include first jquery then the bootstrap.js see my updated jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/vhu0z9xs/

```css
.navbar{
  background-color: #D9F7F6;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
body{
  background-color: #E6E7E7;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="main">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!--COLLAPSE BUTTON FOR NAVBAR MENU-->
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#menu-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">PRADIP KHADKA</a>
      </div><!--END NAVBAR HEADER-->
      <div class="nav-collapse navbar-collapse collapse" id="menu-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" id="navMenu">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SOCIAL MEDIA</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--END OF NAVBAR MENUS-->
    </div><!--END OF NAVBAR CONTAINER-->
  </div><!--END OF NAVBAR-->
</div><!--END OF MAIN CONTAINER-->
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. I would always include jquery first from now onwards.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery before Bootstrap JS file

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

you require to choose jquery version 11.0 in javascript window as bootstrap use jquery. 
please check this one. 
    `<div/>`https://jsfiddle.net/mhdnp1234/9bydt08L/5/